# Isotope with Drawers

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I'm stuck and really need help! I have a layout of bricks that I am using jquery isotope to layout. There are three brick sizes: square, double-wide and double-square, so they fit into place perfectly. What I need to do is have a drawer open up below a brick when you click it, and push any bricks below down as far as needed for the height of the drawer. Here's a mockup to explain what I am trying to do:

[Bricks with Drawer http://bdub.ca/bricks_drawer.jpg](http://bdub.ca/bricks_drawer.jpg)

In this example the orange brick was clicked and the drawer opens up at the next line break, which is after the red brick. The drawer will always be half-width as in the mockup.

Any ideas? I'm at a loss so any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you put together a fiddle of what you have so far? It would be easier to have a look at.

Comment: Are the orange and red bricks related in any way?  If not then I don't know that you have any control on what appears below.  You can insert but only to the left or right.  isotop will determine of it needs to wrap

Comment: My only idea would be to expand the height and width of the orange brick and call 'relowout' - http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#relayout

Answer (score 0):

A solution suggested by Jason Sperske:

http://jsfiddle.net/thomasNDS/5fNe9/2/

This example expand the size of the a block on click and relayout others.

```
          $items.click(function(){ // $items regroup all item display
            var $this = $(this);
            // nothing to change if this already has large class
            if ( $this.hasClass('large') ) { 
              $this.removeClass('large');
            }else{
                var $previousLargeItem = $items.filter('.large');
                $previousLargeItem.removeClass('large');
                $this.addClass('large');
            }
             $container.isotope( 'reLayout' );
          });
```

You can adjust this code to your example with your 3 differents sizes of blocks.